# Format cell with prefix from another cell

Tags: excel, excel-2013

I am looking for a way to insert a text prefix to specific cells from ANOTHER cell in a different sheet. For example:

Sheet 2 Cell A1 contains the text "prefix"
When I enter any text or numbers in Sheet 1 Cell A1 it will say "prefixTEXT".

I was able to find a way to add a prefix to cells by formatting a cell with a custom type "prefix"@. But this prefix changes rather regularly so I was hoping for an easier way for me to just input the prefix into anther cell on my information sheet and have the formatting pull the information from that cell. Does that make sense?

Comment: You will need to create a worksheet_change event to do this.

Comment: Since you didn't use the excel-vba tag, I'll assume a script is not acceptable.  In which case, the only way would be to use `CONCATENATE` in 2nd column.  `A1` would contain **TEXT** and use `=CONCATENATE('Sheet2'!A1," ",A1)` in Sheet 1

Comment: @pnuts The better solution would be to name `Sheet2!A1` as *prefix* and use `=prefix&A1`... could do this all day...